# Excel Dynamic Chart for Each Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in the range of G9:T375. The table is static, not dynamic. It has a constant number of rows a columns that will not change. Now the headers are in the range G9:T9, so in row 9. G column contains dates for each days of the year 2024. Column H contains corresponding names for those days. Column I contains number of the week, first full week starting with Monday and ending with Sunday in the year has 1 assigned to it. So for the 01.01.2024 (Monday) 07.01.2024 (Sunday), the 7 cells in the column I have 1 in them. Next 7 cells contain 2 since it is the 2nd full week of the year, and so on. In the same fashion is filled column J, but instead of weeks, it contains numbers for months. Since January has 31 days, the first 31 cells in the column J contain 1, and so on. Column K contain the year. Since the table consists of 366 rows (not counting the headers) for each single day/date of 2024, every cell in the column K contains 2024. Column L contains number of tasks for each day, column M number of tasks done for each day. There are 7 more columns of data after column M, but they are insignificant for this problem. Now the header of the column L reads "No. Tasks" and header for column M is "Done". Now, I repeat again, the table is static it will not change it's range/dimensions. I use formulas to fill columns L and M with data from a different sheet. So these columns contain either 0 or a different number that has been input on the other sheet.

Now what I would like to do. I want to create a line chart that, based on the current month, will take the corresponding data from the columns L and M and display it on the chart. There is cell J6 that contains formula =MONTH(TODAY()) that returns number for the current month. Today, given it is the 21.01.2024 over here, it returns 1 for January. Now, based on what number this function returns I want Excel to find all the rows in the table which contain 1 in the column J, find the corresponding data in the columns L and M, and display it on the line chart. I have little experience with Excel and has been trying to figure it out for half of the day but all my attempts have been unsuccessful. I would really appreciate help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I might suggest you break this question up into sections or reduce the blockish paragraph appearance. Just glancing at this reminds me of a high school English assignment related to Leo Tolstoy's *Anna Karenina*

Comment: Using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables you could update your question with actual (dummy) data, so you don't need to be as descriptive on the table as you are now and it's easier for somebody to start helping.

Comment: Without any data to play with, and some discrepancy in the detail ("*constant number of rows a columns*" where "a" is possibly "and" but who can tell?) I would be looking to use index() with match() where match() picks with several criteria - many examples on here that are worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the table.
It looks like this.

Use a combination of filter function and choosecols function to create a sub-table of your source table filtering by the month no. then create a chart based on the filtered results.

[image]

Format your source data as excel table (ctrl+T). For me is named Table1
on cell v9 `=CHOOSECOLS(Table1[#Headers],1,2,6,7)`
on cell v10 `=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table1,J6=Table1[Month No],""),1,2,6,7)`
Select V09:Y39 so that you have selected 31+1 rows and create your graph.
end result below

[image]